# Otherwise Usage

Tags: anaphora

According to this definition 3 for "*otherwise*" in this [dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/otherwise?q=otherwise), "*otherwise*" could mean:

> def 3:  in a different way to the way mentioned

An example usage is also provided:

> I wanted to see him but he was ***otherwise engaged***.

The definition of "*otherwise*" requires a previously mentioned way of acting.  But the example sentence contains no mention of an alternate engagement alternate to the engagement referred to by "*otherwise engaged*".  Would the following rewrite:

> I wanted to see him ***so he could talk about some matter***, but he was ***otherwise engaged***.

be better, because the alternate engagement (so he could talk about some matter) is explicitly indicated?

EDIT:  This second [example](http://www.nytimes.com/1991/03/05/opinion/topics-of-the-times-the-stealth-bill.html):

> When government officials aren't terribly proud of what they're doing, they often resort to the Friday afternoon press release, hoping that the media will be ***otherwise occupied***, along with sources reporters might consult for comment. That's the route the Justice Department followed when, at sundown last Friday, it released its 1991 civil rights legislation; afterward, officials who could discuss the bill were hard to find.

does not quite explain explicitly what else the media would do on a Friday afternoon if they were not "*otherwise occupied*".  Could this be wrong too?

Comment: The speaker proposed a "desired engagement" with the person; the speaker wanted to see him. However, he was "otherwise engaged," which is taken to imply that he was seeing someone else at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the example from the dictionary, the "previously mentioned way of acting" was "being seen by me", I suppose.  I wanted him to be seen by me, but he was otherwise engaged[, so he couldn't be seen by me].

Your second example ("..so he could talk") suggests his inability to talk because he was busy, not the inability to be seen by you.

Comment: I added a second example.  Do you think that second example is poorly written?

Comment: Poorly, no.  The "otherwise engaged", "otherwise occupied", etc., can also **imply** the "previously mentioned way of acting".  In your second example, "government officials" hope that the press would not pay attention to what they declare on Fridays.  Paying attention *is* that alternative way of acting.

Comment: So, that the "paying attention to press releases" part is not mentioned, is okay?

Comment: Yes, quite clear.